# Difference of "+=" operator and string concatenation in memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, concatenation, accumulator

In a book I read I learned that standard string concatenation can be hard on memory as it copies the string itself each time and adds the new values.

```
message = message + chr(codeNum)
```

I wonder if it is the same thing with the += operator.

```
message += chr(codeNum)
```

I saw some similar topics on other languages, but my question is mainly about Python. Can you spare some knowledge on this?

Comment: Python strings are immutable, so it doesn't matter whether the addition operation is binary or inline -- either way the result is something else than the original string, so a new one will be created with all the associated overhead.

Comment: What happens is that strings are immutable and once it binds to a variable it won't be possible to change it. When a string is 'modified' it actually is a new string reassigned to the same variable. So I would say there is no significant difference in what operator is used to make a concatenation .

Comment: There's a weird and somewhat fragile optimization in the CPython implementation that tries to perform this operation mutatively, but the optimization doesn't care whether you use `+` or `+=`.

Comment: (Don't rely on the weird optimization. Build up a list of stuff to concatenate and use `''.join` to concatenate it all in one go. That works on all Python implementations and is guaranteed not to degrade to quadratic performance.)

Comment: In some languages it is the idiom to build up long strings by repeated concatenation, as you do in your example. Because it is inefficient to do this in Python, the idiom is to assemble a temporary list of short strings (extending a list is much more efficient than reallocating a string) and to create a long string by a single call to `join()` when the list is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure this out by using the timeit module, it certainly looks like they are equivalent methods:

```
>>> s = timeit.Timer(stmt="s1 = 'str1';s2 = 'str2';s1 = s1 + s2")
>>> s.timeit()
0.04924579999999423

>>> s3 = timeit.Timer(stmt="s1 = 'str1';s2 = 'str2';s1 += s2")
>>> s3.timeit()
0.0429421999999704
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. This can be proven by simple benchmark.

**50 invocations of 1000000 iterations.**

```
import timeit
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(50):
        print(timeit.timeit(stmt='msg = msg + chr(33)', setup='msg=""'))
```

Avg. **0.1719**

```
import timeit
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(50):
        print(timeit.timeit(stmt='msg += char(33)', setup='msg=""'))
```

Avg. **0.1748**